# Open a web link in windows form (Vb.Net)

Tags: vb.net, web-applications, c#-to-vb.net

I want to open a web page that was created by me, by passing parameters to that web link,
I try to open it like this:

```
 Dim aaa As String = String.Format _
("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\web site 1\HRMSExport1.aspx", _
"?_mchno={0}&_batch={1}&_Points={2}&_ovrpt={3}&_gstrID={4}& _ 
_gstrPassword={5}&_gstrDataSource={6}&_gstrCatalog={7}", _
cmbMachine.Text, txtBatch.Text, inpstd, _
Overpoints, gstrID, gstrPassword, gstrDataSource, gstrCatalog)
Process.Start(aaa)
```

but it fails.
How to open a web link with parameters??

Comment: Please, note that, if you open the *.aspx file by its physical address, it wouldn't be working, because IIS and .NET Framework wouldn't know anything about it. You should use `http://localhost/web site 1/HRMSExport1.aspx`

Answer (score 1):

Your String.Format command and line breaks are incorrect.  On line 2, replace the comma with an ampersand.  On line 3, you cannot use a line continuation inside a String.  Close the string, use the line continuation, then add the rest of the string.

Try:

```
Dim commandline As String = String.Format _
    ("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\web site 1\HRMSExport1.aspx" & _
    "?_mchno={0}&_batch={1}&_Points={2}&_ovrpt={3}&_gstrID={4}&" & _
    "_gstrPassword={5}&_gstrDataSource={6}&_gstrCatalog={7}", _
    _cmbMachine.Text, txtBatch.Text, inpstd, Overpoints, gstrID, _
    gstrPassword, gstrDataSource, gstrCatalog)
Process.Start(commandline)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two format strings being passed to your string.format

Try this:

```
    Dim aaa As String = String.Format _
    ("C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\web site 1\HRMSExport1.aspx?_mchno={0}&_batch={1}&_Points={2}&_ovrpt={3}&_gstrID={4}&_gstrPassword={5}&_gstrDataSource={6}&_gstrCatalog={7}", _
    cmbMachine.Text, txtBatch.Text, inpstd, Overpoints, gstrID, gstrPassword, gstrDataSource, gstrCatalog)
    Process.Start(aaa)
```